# Getting bad operand types for binary operator '*' error

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am wanting to output the assignment score the user input multiplied by the assignment weight of 50%. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

  String studentID = "";
  String firstName = "";
  String lastName  = "";
  String assignmentScore = "";
  String quizScore = "";
  String midtermExamScore = "";
  String finalExamScore = "";
  int choice = 0;
  double assignmentWeight = 0.5;
  double quizWeight = 0.2;
  double midtermWeight = 0.1;
  double finalWeight = 0.2;
  double homework = assignmentScore * assignmentWeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't multiply `String` and `Double` data types. Which means `double = String * double`

Comment: So do I need to change the double that holds the weight to something else?  What would I use?

Comment: No, you can't type cast it from `double` to `String` or vice versa. One more thing i didn't get why your storing `assignmentScore ` in `String`. Change it's type to `double`.

Comment: I get an error saying incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double.

Comment: change the `assignmentScore` to `double`